# How to get all the checked checkboxes in an array using pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
var subject = document.getElementsByClassName("subject");

var checkboxesChecked =[];

for (var i=0; i<2; i++) {
    // And stick the checked ones onto an array...
    if (subject[i].checked===true) {
        checkboxesChecked.push(subject[i]);
    }
}
```

It always return me `[object HTMLCollection]` and on view instead of checkboxes Object Object is displayed.

Comment: So you've got an array of checkboxes that were checked; what did you want to do with that array that's not working? Incidentally, if you can share your (*[mcve]*) HTML (and potentially CSS) then we're more likely to be able to help you.

Comment: *"instead of checkboxes Object Object is displayed"* `[object Object]` is the default string representation of an object, so that seems fine. Since you don't explain what the expected result is, we can't really help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `subject[i].value` to get the value of the `checkbox` and push that into the array.

Change your code to:

```
var subject = document.getElementsByClassName("subject");

var checkboxesChecked =[];

for (var i=0; i<2; i++) {
    // And stick the checked ones onto an array...
    if (subject[i].checked===true) {
        checkboxesChecked.push(subject[i].value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? OP says "all checkboxes"